# How to drop the index column of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to get rid of the index column that the Pandas DataFrame prints out in default. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no display option I can find that can do this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option, you could do `print(df.values)` but this outputs a numpy array without the column names so not that readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @EdChum noted, not sure there's any way to do this by default.  For display purposes, you could do:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```